# The intuition behind recursive math formula's

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion, fibonacci-numbers

I am working on a problem case to try gaining more intuition behind recursion and mathematical formula's. I understand how to solve the case by using code and recursion. However, I find the mathematical formula less intuitive.

The case is: an object has to cover 11 feet to reach it's end destination. It can take moves of 1 feet or 2 feet. Find out in how many ways the object can cover 11 feet, f(11)?

The solution follows the "Fibonacci-method" to generate the answer (providing the answer on the number of ways the object can reach the 11th step). I can code this by using a recursive function that returns the sum of the two previous states (n-1 and n-2).

So the solution states that this problem case follows the following function:

```
f(n+2) = f(n+1) + f(n)
```

So if we take f(3):

```
f(1+2) = f(1+1) + f(1) -> f(3) = f(2) + f(1)
```

But why should the answer of f(3) be the sum of the previous two states? Why does that make sense in this case where the object can take either 1 or 2 feet-moves?

Answer (score 1):

We can't move by $3$ feets directly.

So we must have achieved that by a sequence of $1$ or $2$ feets that sum up to $3$.

Let's condition on the last move.

To use $2$ feet as our last move, we must have taken the $2$ feet move from $1$ feet location. To reach the $1$ feet location, there are $f(1)$ ways.

To use $1$ feet as our last move, we must have taken the $1$ feet move from $2$ feet location.  To reach the $2$ feet location, there are $f(2)$ ways.

Hence $$f(3)=f(1)+f(2)$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer Siong Thye Goh. It seems to make a bit more sense now. However, how would this reasoning hold when we would look for f(4). In that case the sum of the previous to states do not add up to 4 feet (e.g. sum of 3 and  2 feet results in 5.). Or am I confusing two things?

Comment: Again, we can condition on the last move, to use $2$-feet as our last move, we must have takent the $2$ feet move from the $2$ feet location, To Reach the $2$-feet location, there are $f(2)$ ways. To use $1$ feet as our last move, we must have taken $1$ feet from the $3$-feet location. To reach the $3$ feet location, there are $f(3)$ ways.

Comment: Ah, I got it. Thank you Siong Thye Goh! This makes perfect sense!